# Setting up collision groups in farseer

Tags: farseer

I'm trying to set up collision groups in Farseer so that the items in the picture collide as follows:

- G1 Collides with All.
- B1 and B2 collide with each other and G1, but not R1 or R2
- R1 and R2 collide with each other and G1, but not B1 or B2.

[image: CollisionGroups]

I've been playing around with `_Body.CollidesWith = Category.Cat1;` and `_Body.CollisionCategories = ...`, but I'm basically just guessing. Haven't really found any usefull examples in the docs, but I might not have been looking in the right place either.

**Edit 1:**

Ok, so experimenting some more.

Assuming `_Body` is B1 (and also applied to B2) in the picture, and Cat1 is G1, and Cat2 is all blue items..

```
_Body.CollidesWith = Category.Cat1 & Category.Cat2;
_Body.CollisionCategories = Category.Cat2;
```

Should this not then allow B1 to collide with the ground (G1) and all other blues (B# items)?
Applying the above code makes all blue items collide with nothing not even each other...

Answer (score 1):

```
_Body.CollisionCategories = Category.Cat1 | Category.Cat2;
```

instead of

```
_Body.CollisionCategories = Category.Cat1 & Category.Cat2;
```